# Should I create service for GPS tracking APP?

Tags: android, gps

I am writing a location service App that log where the user has been every minute.
Should I create a service for the GPS process? OR just create the LocationManager at the Activity? Which one is better?

Moreover, I have tried to hide the application by pressing hardware home button and turn off GPS at Setting -> Location. I found that the App closed automatically within an hour.
Is it possible to keep the application always alive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I highly recommend creating the gps at the very least as a thread in the activity, if you want to be slick set it up as a service and broadcast intents from inside an asynctask. Setting it up as a service makes it a bit modular if you want to use it for other applications or in other activities. Thats the way I implemented it.

Its also easier to control the lifetime of your gps readings if you run it from a service instead of your activity, so service doesnt get interrupted if you do switch activities etc.. example of asynctask portion below:

```
    /** Begin async task section ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    private class PollTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> { //AsyncTask that listens for locationupdates then broadcasts via "LOCATION_UPDATE" 
        // Classwide variables
        private boolean trueVal = true;
        Location locationVal;
        //Setup locationListener
        LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener(){ //overridden abstract class LocationListener
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                handleLocationUpdate(location);
            }
            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                    Bundle extras) {
            }
        };

        /** Overriden methods */
        @Override 
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) { 
            //This is where the magic happens, load your stuff into here
            while(!isCancelled()){ // trueVal Thread will run until you tell it to stop by changing trueVal to 0 by calling method cancelVal(); Will also remove locationListeners from locationManager
                Log.i("service","made it to do in background");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                }
            return null; 

        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled(){
            super.onCancelled();
            stopSelf();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){ // Performed prior to execution, setup location manager
            locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            if(gpsProvider==true){
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
            }
            if(networkProvider==true){
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
            }
        }

        @Override 
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) { //Performed after execution, stopSelf() kills the thread
            stopSelf(); 
        } 

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... v){ //called when publishProgress() is invoked within asynctask
                //On main ui thread, perform desired updates, potentially broadcast the service use notificationmanager
                /** NEED TO BROADCAST INTENT VIA sendBroadCast(intent); */
                Intent intent = new Intent(LOCATION_UPDATE);
                //Put extras here if desired
                intent.putExtra(ACCURACY, locationVal.getAccuracy()); // float double double long int
                intent.putExtra(LATITUDE, locationVal.getLatitude());
                intent.putExtra(LONGITUDE, locationVal.getLongitude());
                intent.putExtra(TIMESTAMP, locationVal.getTime());
                intent.putExtra(ALTITUDE,locationVal.getAltitude());
                intent.putExtra(NUM_SATELLITES,0);/////////////****TEMP
                sendBroadcast(intent); //broadcasting update. need to create a broadcast receiver and subscribe to LOCATION_UPDATE
                Log.i("service","made it through onprogress update");
        }

        /** Custom methods */

        private void cancelVal(){ //Called from activity by stopService(intent) --(which calls in service)--> onDestroy() --(which calls in asynctask)--> cancelVal()
            trueVal = false;
            locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
        }

        private void handleLocationUpdate(Location location){ // Called by locationListener override.
            locationVal = location;
            publishProgress();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks. What I concern is when the system kill the Activity/GPS service. As you said, 'I highly recommend creating the gps at the very least as a thread in the activity'. Is it better to create the GPS at a thread in a Activity? Is it possible that the system kill that GPS thread if the hide the app and idle for some time?

Comment: if you are concerned about lifetime control, first off, just go for a service. and the answer to your question in the event of using a service, is that the service will continue to run even after your kill your activity unless you explicitly decide to end it in your onDestroy() method in your activity. You can stop the service with by intent and the stopService(intent) command, just like you start with startService(intent) -- within the service onDestroy command you will want to call cancelVal() (or whatever you implement it as) in the asynctask. google lifetime of acitivities and services.