# Background Process for a gps app

Tags: android, gps, maps

I have a button " track my location " which uses GPS and tracks my location successfully. But when i click on the back button , the tracking stops. I want the tracking to go in in the background, even if the user switches over to any other application

I want this function to run in the background

```
private void centerOnLocation()
{
loc = locman.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
if(loc != null)
{
lat = loc.getLatitude();
    lon = loc.getLongitude();
    templat=lat;
    templon=lon;

    System.out.println("TrackedLat:"+loc);
    System.out.println("temporaryyyyyyyyyyyyyy");
    System.out.println("Templat:"+templat);
    System.out.println("TempLon:"+templon);
    System.out.println("matlat matlon");
    System.out.println("TrackedLon:"+matlat);
    System.out.println("TrackedLon:"+matlon);
Log.i(TAG+"_loc",loc.toString());   
Log.i(TAG, "Lat="+lat+" lon="+lon);
GeoPoint newPoint = new GeoPoint((int)(lat*1e6),(int)(lon*1e6));   
mapControl.animateTo(newPoint);
getSatelliteData();
if(displayOverlay != null){
displayOverlay.putSatStuff(lat, lon, satAccuracy, bearing, altitude,
speed, currentProvider, numberSats);
}

}
  functiontocompare(matlat,matlon,templat,templon);
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617957/should-i-create-service-for-gps-tracking-app

Answer (score 2):

> I want the tracking to go in in the background, even if the user
>   switches over to any other application

then you need to Integrate a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) for Tracking from background even user switches over to any other application

And for Storing User Loction Use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) or Sqlite database.

For Communicate between Service or Activity use Custom [BroadcastReciver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).

[Communication between service and activity](http://androidexperinz.wordpress.com/2012/02/14/communication-between-service-and-activity-part-1/)